# What's the meaning of the expression "toma chocolate paga lo que debe"?

Tags: expresiones, significado, cuba

What's the meaning of the expression "**toma chocolate paga lo que debe**"?

I hear this expression in the song "El Bodeguero", by Nat King Cole.
I believe that's a Cuban expression.

Comment: It seems that the expression is "toma chocolate, paga lo que debes". The second part is straightforward, so you should ask for the meaning of the first part. Welcome to [Spanish.SE]!

Comment: It means: Here's your chocolate. Pay what you owe. Toma is used like that in Spanish in a semi-rude way to say: Here is X, when someone asks for something. Toma el dinero. Ya estoy libre de mi deuda contigo. For example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, this is an expression that is still used in Cuba.

[La confitería de la viuda](http://www.delaviuda.com/blog/toma-chocolate-paga-lo-que-debes-2/) says:

> Esta frase se sigue utilizando a día de hoy, sobre todo en Cuba.
>   **Quiere decir que disfrutes de todo lo que quieras, pero págalo.**
>
> Cuentan los lugareños que esta frase nació a raíz de una historia.
>   Un personaje que se hizo famoso en su pueblo porque siempre pedía chocolate, se lo tomaba y luego se iba sin pagar.
>   La frase se extendió a otras muchas situaciones, como pedir dinero y no devolverlo, comprar y no terminar de pagar lo que se compraba, etc.
>
> Así que ya sabes, todo aquello que quieras tiene un precio y hay que pagarlo.

So it means: **enjoy as much as you want, but pay for it**.

---

In [a comment](http://refranescubanos.blogspot.com.es/2007/08/toma-chocolatey-paga-lo-que-debes.html?showComment=1186695000000#c8858331215635303823) to a post in the page Refranes cubanos, they mention another hypothesis:

> el refrán viene de una persona a la cual llmaban "chocolate", y estaba siempre endeudado. Le hicieron un préstamo para que pagara y la frase, con buena puntuación se leería:
>
> - "Toma, chocolate, paga lo que debes".

---

Note that this is a very nice example to show the importance of punctuation.

- *Toma chocolate paga lo que debes* is difficult to understand as is.
- *Toma chocolate, paga lo que debes* it states two sentences *toma chocolate* and *paga lo que debes*, one being the consequence of the other.
- *Toma, chocolate, paga lo que debes* it can address a person whose nick name is *chocolate* and say "hey, here you have some money; now, pay back your debts".

But what must be the meaning in the context of this song? Let's check the lyrics:

> Siempre en su casa, presente está
>   El bodeguero y el cha cha cha
>   Vete a la esquina y lo veras
>   Y atento siempre te servirá
>
> Anda enseguida córrete allá
>   El con la plata lo encontrarás
>   Del otro lado del mostrador
>   El complaciente y servidor
>
> Bodeguero que sucede
>   Porque tan contento estás
>   Yo creo que es consecuencia
>   De lo que en moda está
>
> El bodeguero bailando va
>   En la bodega se baila así
>   [Entre frijóles papa y ají](https://youtu.be/AQpeQXFPEZs?t=1m6s)
>   El nuevo ritmo del cha cha cha
>
> [Toma chocolate. Paga lo que debes](https://youtu.be/AQpeQXFPEZs?t=1m15s)
>   Toma chocolate. Paga lo que debes
>   Toma chocolate. Paga lo que debes
>   Toma chocolate. Paga lo que debes
>   Toma chocolate. Paga lo que debes
>   Toma chocolate
>
> En la bodega se baila así
>   Entre frijoles papa hay aquí
>   En la bodega se baila así
>   Entre frijóles papa y ají
>
> Toma chocolate. Paga lo que debes
>   Toma chocolate. Paga lo que debes
>   Toma chocolate. Paga lo que debes
>   Toma chocolate

Given this context, of a man who owns a tavern, it is most likely that the meaning has to do with "hey, have fun here but do pay the bill!".

Comment: @DGaleano ¡muchísimas gracias por las correcciones!

Answer (score 1):

It is a special-case form of the proverb: "Toma lo que quieres, y paga por ello, dice Dios." An example in an essay by Marco Provencioat at www.milenio.com (25.12.2015)  [here](https://www.milenio.com/opinion/marco-provencio/la-intemperie/toma-chocolate-paga-lo-que-debes) says:

> Cada vez es más evidente la sabiduría del proverbio español aquél que dice que "... Y Dios le dijo al hombre, 'toma lo que deseas, y paga por ello'". ¡Cuánto hemos tomado, y cuánto más hemos tenido que pagar y vamos a tener que seguir pagando! Tanto en un sentido literal como figurativo, hemos tomado demasiado... de la tierra, de los mares, del espíritu, del trabajo del hombre.

A blogger at pensamientoscordeanos.blogspot.com (date 2010-12-09) says:

> Básicamente esto significa que puedes tener todo lo que quieras en la vida, pero tienes que pagar.. ya sea en tiempo, en esfuerzo en sudor o en lágrimas.

Here are two parables expressing a similar sentiment:

> Nadie comienza a construir una torre, si no se sienta primero, y calcula el costo de ella; de otra forma, queda a mitad el proyecto, y los vecinos se reirán de él.
>
> De la misma forma, ningún rey trabará guerra con otro, si no considera que tiene la posición estratégica y logística para hacerle frente al enemigo; y si no la tiene, envía al rey que viene en su contra y le pide términos de paz. - *paraphrase from the Bible: Gospel according to Luke, ch. 14*

It is that, in the first place, you can have pretty much whatever you want; but in the end you should pay for it. If you don't pay voluntarily, you'll still be forced to one way or another, which is why this proverb also should make you think about what you will pay in relation to what you are enjoying now.

It could be extrapolated to long-term investments, something like this in brutish prose: "Choose what is your first priority, and don't let anything distract you or take away energy that should be going toward fulfilling that first choice."

Comment: Welcome to Spanish.SE! Which is the source of this citation? Is it New Testament? May you please add it to your post?

Answer (score 0):

Esta frase está dividida en dos acciones, las cuales contienen sabiduría popular y encierran un significado o simbolismo para refererirse a acciones cotidianas de la vida de las personas.
En los países latinos se usan mucho los "dichos" y los "refranes", expresiones populares de sabiduría que aplican a situaciones de la vida de las personas, en este caso.

1. **¡Toma chocolate!:** Encierra la acción de por ejemplo ir a una cafetería, sentarte en una mesa, pedir al mesero una rica y sabrosa taza de chocolate y degustarla.
2. **¡Paga lo que debes!:** La segunda parte de la expresión, simboliza a otra persona que increpa a la que disfrutó de la taza de chocolate, y le dice en forma simbólica: "Si ya disfrutaste de tu taza sabrosa de chocolate, ahora debes esa taza y debes pagarla".

El corolario a dicha expresión es:
que si pides o compras algo y lo disfruta por adelantado, una vez que hagas uso de ello, debes entonces pagar por ese servicio.

Comment: Sí, se divide en dos. El chocolate era importado, el café, no.

Answer (score 0):

Revisando las respuestas y viendo la letra completa de la canción, He encontrado el sentido de la frase: la escena es que en la bodega, un cubano de color pide su consumición y el bodeguero se la sirve, soltándole a continuación: toma, “chocolate”; paga lo que debes... refiriéndose la palabra “chocolate” no a la bebida caliente a base de cacao, sino al mote o apodo dado a esa persona de color, no sé si solo a esa en concreto o a todos los negros en general, eso lo podrá decir alguien cubano. No me cuadraba que en una bodega se sirviera chocolate, por eso conociendo el ambiente informal de una bodega y del bodeguero, y viendo el sentido de la canción, encuentro que esa es la explicación más lógica.

Comment: Podría ser, pero qué te hace llegar a esa conclusión? En la letra de la canción no hay ninguna referencia a la raza, y tampoco he encontrado ninguna fuente que indique que la expresión "Toma chocolate" esté relacionada con la raza. Si tienes una fuente que apoye esta hipótesis, sería útil que la incluyeras en la respuesta.

Comment: No creo por nada. Orquestra Aragón no cantaría algo que podría interpretarse como racista. Eran todos afro-cubanos Las bodegas servian bebidas y **es posible** que el chocolate era más caro que el café o qualquier alcool porque era importado de África. Richard Egües, el flautista y compositor de la canción también era afro-cubano. Assisti a un concierto de ellos en Paris en el año de la punga. :) https://folkways.si.edu/orquesta-aragon/recorded-live-in-new-york/cuba-latin-world/music/album/smithsonian

Comment: Ademas, Egües explica que pasó una noche entera componiendo la canción. A veces, los compositores necesitan una palabra con mas sílabas e eso le vino a la cabeza. https://www.nostalgiacuba.com/la-historia-de-la-cancion-el-bodeguero-de-la-orquesta-aragon-toma-chocolate/